# Deeper Facebook Integration in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am an admin of a Facebook Page. Now it want to involve it in my MVC Project. I was wondering if it is possible to :

1)fetch its data (such as profile pic ,about,events,who is attending etc) from fb and showing it in my ASP MVC View.

2) involve all the features provided by fb (to the page)in MVC project. e.g. creating an event, adding photos and videos.

3) is there any way to Authorize forms via fb authentication.

if this is achivable how should i proceed? what are the prerequisites?

any blog/link/tutorial/study material for this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a clean API you can use to integrate it into your applications. It's called the Graph API, they have the docs on their site:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/coreconcepts/

The Graph API is designed to perform various operations, if something is to be done, it can be done via the Graph API.

As for the authentication, yes, it's fairly simple, Facebook implements the OAuth2 protocol. Just google on "C# OAuth2 Facebook" or something similar and you will get links to complete tutorials.

The docs from Facebook team are here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/